# is it good add more nested component in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am new to angular 4. I am working on crud operation. I have doubt on creating the component for a list, add and edit. Here I have doubt. Is it good to create a sperate component for edit and save and list either can I use only one component for all crud operation?. which way is the fast one single component or nested component pattern?.

I am a little bit confused here. Please guide me, anyone.

Comment: I wouldn't separate components by actions, but what they are for group of actions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be great if you have just one component for all of these operations, here are some reason that I feel having one for all will help,

1. Your final bundle will have less codes(lightweight).
2. Your operations(CRUD) will be centralized.
3. If you create separate component for all these operations you will land up merging them in one view that could cause integration issues and will be unnecessarily complex.